# How do I find if a substring exists in a string using a specifier?

Tags: c

I have a file with radio frequences of this type

```
Radio One 104.3
Radio Two 106.3
```

And I have to pass to the program the name of the radio or the frequence. If I pass the name of the radio or a float number it goes in segmentation fault. I have to use the specifier `%[^set]` to find the name of the radio in the cass that I pass a frequence in the terminal. How can I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("frequenze.txt", "r");
    char radio[100];
    float frequenza;

    if(isalpha(argv[1]) != 0){
        while(fgets(radio, 100, in) == radio){
            if(strncmp(argv[1], radio, strlen(argv[1])) == 0){
                printf("%s\n", radio);
            }
        }
    }
    if(isdigit(argv[1]) != 0){
        while(fscanf(in, "%[^%f]", &frequenza) == 1){
            if(frequenza == atof(argv[1])){
                fgets(radio, 100, in);
                printf("%s\n", radio);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187819/discussion-on-question-by-user11006304-how-do-i-find-if-a-substring-exists-in-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small as it is, this program still offers quite some opportunities for more or less subtle errors.

- It should be checked whether a program argument is given at all.
- With `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`, only a character can be tested, not a whole string. Perhaps you meant `isalpha(*argv[1])` and `isdigit(*argv[1])`.
- Using a conversion specification in a character class (as `[^%f]`) is imaginative, but not working. Also you cannot re-read a line from `in` from the beginning without an *fseek* operation. Better read name and frequency together right from the outset.
- The comparison `frequenza == atof(argv[1])` fails due to the different precision of the operands (`float frequenza` vs. `double atof()`).

```
    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    if (isalpha(*argv[1]))
        while (fgets(radio, 100, in) == radio)
            if (strncmp(argv[1], radio, strlen(argv[1])) == 0)
                printf("%s", radio);
    if (isdigit(*argv[1]))
        while (fscanf(in, "%[^0-9]%f ", radio, &frequenza) == 2)
            if (frequenza == (float)atof(argv[1]))
                printf("%s%g\n", radio, frequenza);
```

Comment: If you use *argv[1] are you referring only to the first char or to the whole string? Is *argv[1] the same as argv[1][0]?

Comment: Using %[^0-9] means that you are storing a string but as soon as you find a number included between 0 and 9 it stops scanning?

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't print the radio string but it prints the frequence. I did exactly as you did. The first if works, but the second doesn't.

Comment: @user11006304 - `*argv[1]` is the first `char` of the string `argv[1]`, yes, the same as `argv[1][0]`.

Comment: @user11006304 - Yes, `%[^0-9]` stores a string (including spaces) until a digit is found. Note that this implies that the radio station name cannot contain digits.

Comment: @user11006304 - _it doesn't print the radio string_ - What program argument exactly did you give? Can you show a hexdump of the "frequenze.txt"? Which OS do you use?